# Vimeo Froogaloop API not recognizing an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm trying to recognize the onPlay, onPause, and onFinish event for vimeo using the froogaloop API. I've tried everything I could imagine with this thing, and no luck.

I get this error on Firefox:

[image: Permission denied for <code><http://player.vimeo.com></code> to get pet property Location.toString]

And in Chrome:

[image: Unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with URL ... from frame with URL `http://player.vimeo.com/video/3718294?api=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.]

Importing froogaloop from the CDN:

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
```

My JS:

```
$(function(){

    var vimeoPlayer = document.querySelector('iframe');

    $f(vimeoPlayer).addEvent('ready', ready);

    function ready(player_id) {

        froogaloop = $f(player_id);

        function setupEventListeners() {
            function onPlay() {
                froogaloop.addEvent('play',
                function(data) {
                    console.log('play event');
                });
            }

            function onPause() {

                froogaloop.addEvent('pause',
                function(data) {
                    console.log('pause event');
                });
            }

            function onFinish() {
                froogaloop.addEvent('finish',
                function(data) {
                    console.log('finish');
                });
            }
            onPlay();
            onPause();
            onFinish();
        }
        setupEventListeners();
    }

})
```

My HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/3718294?api=1" width="623" height="350" frameborder="0" id="iframe-video"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

After hours and hours of frustration... I have found the solution.

Since I was using an ID on the iframe... apparently the vimeo API forces you to add the parameter to the URL you are fetching (player_id=iframe-id).

So the iFrame should look like this:

```html
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/3718294?api=1&player_id=promo-vid" 
        width="623" height="350" frameborder="0"
        id="promo-vid">
</iframe>
```

Special thanks to Drew Baker for pointing this out: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:38114#comment_5043696

Comment: I made an example of how to use the Vimeo API here: http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

Comment: I'm still slogging through the 'hours of frustration' part.  When I follow the examples given all I get are javascript security policy violations.  How did you overcome these?

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me - if I look at Drew Baker's example or implement the answer above I still get unsafe javascript errors - the player works, but the errors do not go away.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I've found another fix for this: I'm playing the video and then pausing it as soon as the video is ready. This way, when the user tries to play it again, the video plays smoothly.

Comment: Useful link which clearly explains the OP 's question: http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

Answer (score 2):

Got an error creating the player element when selecting the iframe with **jQuery**.

```
var iframe = $('#player1');
var player = $f(iframe);
```

Results in

```
TypeError: d[f] is undefined
```

Solution for me was to select the first element in the jQuery ID selector

```
var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);
```

Comment: Did you get the answer @Max?

Comment: Select the 1. JS object that is inside the jQuery selector with a [0] behind it, as statet at the bottom of my answer...

Comment: I used it, however, I am getting the same error! iframe is undefined if I try to alert the same. Also, using Player_id ,and api=1,

Comment: Can't help you, this worked for me... maybe post your code. greetings

Answer (score 1):

I think you're violating the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You'll notice [here](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/blob/master/javascript/playground.html) that where you're doing a lot of event handling, they are using special froogaloop API calls.

I've never used froogaloop so I'm probably wrong.  But that's my guess.  The errors seem to suggest that the iframe is attempting to modify the URL in your browser, and that's now allowed by Same Origin.  That's why the API wraps up window.postMessage for you.

Comment: What can I do to fix this then?

Comment: Adhere more to their pattern.  For example, look at their SimpleButtons example; their evenListener callbacks are all calls to froogaloop API methods. Since you're adding an event listener to the froogaloop object that is trying to interact with your browser, you have to do it through their API.  Also, looking at their API, I don't see an "addEvent" defined for a froogaloop object, just an addEventListener.  They define their own addEvent in their example code that wraps addEventListener.  Makes me think that there's a problem with using built-in addEvent related to Same Origin.

Comment: I had some similar problem. My video is hidden by default. I tried to show the video first (via jQuery ```somediv.show();``` ), and directly after this, I tried to call the:  ```player.api('play');``` . This results in really strange behavior, where the video doesn't play, or play after 30 seconds or so...


At the end, I just created a separate function (let's say OnPlay), which only contains: ```player.api('play');```. Now the line becomes :
```somediv.show(0, OnPlay)```;

This works! But Why?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but in this case after replacing Froggaloop with the Vimeo.Player, it still it was a new restriction in chrome.  I was getting the error "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first...".  After further research it looks like Chrome added some restrictions [see here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).  The solution in my case was to add `allow="autoplay"` to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a similar issue, with Froggaloop2 - it appears that if the video is cached, the ready event will fire only once (on the initial load). The solution is to retrieve the iframe with changing src, as:

```
$(iframe).attr('src', $(iframe).attr('src') + '#timestamp='+(new Date()).getTime());
```