# Debug Help for Simple Javascript/jQuery Vimeo Froogaloop

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api, froogaloop

See this link: http://jitimanagementcoach.com/TC_test/tabbed4try.html
I've already got the videos to play and/or pause on one tab or another when a tab is clicked... but now **I need the video on the Prelearn tab to "click" the Solution tab and play the video once the Prelearn video is finished**. Here's the code:

```
               <script>
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("prelearnvid");
var iframe2 = document.getElementById("solutionvid");
var player1 = $f(iframe1);
var player2 = $f(iframe2);
var prelearnBtn = document.getElementById("prelearnbtn");
prelearnBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {player1.api("play");player2.api("pause");});

var solutionBtn = document.getElementById("solutionbtn");
solutionBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {player2.api("play");player1.api("pause");});

    player1.addEvent('ready', function() {player1.addEvent('finish', onFinish);});

    function onFinish(id) {window.location.href = '#solution-tab';};

        </script>
```

It all works fine until the very last two lines... where am I going wrong?

Comment: add problem on fiddle please to get error correctly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ready` event is not firing for your player. In order for the player's events to fire, you need to add a `player_id` parameter to your URL that includes the `id` of your `<iframe>`.

Change the `src` attribute of your `<iframe>` to this:

```
<iframe id="prelearnvid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/92349330?&amp;player_id=prelearnvid"
```

From the [Froogaloop documentation](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api):

> If you’re embedding and controlling multiple players on a page or
>   using our JS API library (Froogaloop), you should give each player a
>   `player_id` that matches the id of the iframe element.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537832/859640) and this [forum post](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:38114#comment_5043696) helped uncover this solution.